# How to create HTML table like structure in flex

Tags: html, apache-flex

The html table coding structure looks something like the code shown below
`<table>`
`<tr>`
`<td>Text</td>`
`<td>input text field</td>`
`</tr>`
`<tr>`
`<td></td>`
`<td></td>`
`</tr>`
`<tr>`
`<td>submit butto</td>`
`</tr>`
`</table>`

How to create such table structure in flex which has above given row and column format in flex application with the option of colspann and rowspan alternate too?

Comment: What relationship does this question have to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13004430/create-a-table-like-structure-in-flex)? It may help you to combine the two questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of ways.  I would probably start by looking into the [Form layout container](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WSc5cd04c102ae3e973827a8e912ac2b325a4-8000.html).  That is great for a two column layout, although it gives you little control over the first column which is primarily used for

You could also, in theory, create something like this by using embedded containers, but I do not think I would recommend that approach because I suspect you'll end up with a lot of unnecessary containers.

You could also write your own layout class.  More info on [layouts here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/spark_layouts.html).  This is the most powerful/flexible approach, but probably also the most time consuming.