# Create a table like structure in flex

Tags: html, apache-flex

I want to create a form in a table like structure like we do in html. following is the basic structure i require![enter image description here][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6b3f.png
How to code such a structure?

Answer (score 0):

Use the **[Spark Form](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WSc5cd04c102ae3e973827a8e912ac2b325a4-8000.html)** components.

Example (shamelessly modified from example on the help page):

```
<s:Form id="myForm" width="450" height="125">
    <s:FormHeading label="My Form Title" />
    <s:FormItem label="Name:">
        <s:TextInput id="name" />
        <s:helpContent>
            <s:Label text="Enter your first and last names" />
        </s:helpContent>
    </s:FormItem>
</s:Form>
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>  <div id="header_block">
>       ...... Header_block Contents
>     </div>
>    <div id="wrapper">
>       ...... Entire Page
>     </div>
> ```

css

> ```
>    #header_block
>      {
>            position:fixed;
>            width:100%;
>            float:left;
>       }
> ```